# pandas convert lists in multiple columns within DataFrame to separate columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to convert a list within multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame into separate columns.

Say, I have a dataframe like this:

```
           0          1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
2  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]
```

And would like to convert it to something like this:

```
   0  1  2  0  1  2
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

I have managed to do this in a loop. However, I would like to do this in fewer lines.
My code snippet so far is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
output1 = df[0].apply(pd.Series)
output2 = df[1].apply(pd.Series)

output = pd.concat([output1, output2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want that output? Duplicate column names are allowed but not particularly useful...

Comment: At this point I am not really worried about the duplicated column names. I would like to reduce it to one line instead of implementing what will be loop/concat structure once applied to a dataframe with more than two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the column names you could do:

```
>>> df.apply(np.hstack, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sum`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.sum(1).tolist())
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  6
```